# Sort values based on group

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 3 columns: the index of household,the number of members of each family and the number of trips for each person. How I can sort these columns?

Here is an example

```
  Household  person  trip
      1         1     1
      1         1     2
      1         1     3
      1         2     1
      1         2     3
      1         2     2
      2         1     2
      2         1     1
      2         2     1
      2         2     2
```

So I want the third column to be sorted for each person. As you can see in the first household the trips of the second person need to be sorted and in the second household for the first person

So the output is

```
  Household  person  trip
      1         1     1
      1         1     2
      1         1     3
      1         2     1
      1         2     2
      1         2     3
      2         1     1
      2         1     2
      2         2     1
      2         2     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to use `arrange_all` as there are only three columns

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   arrange_all
#   Household person trip
#1          1      1    1
#2          1      1    2
#3          1      1    3
#4          1      2    1
#5          1      2    2
#6          1      2    3
#7          2      1    1
#8          2      1    2
#9          2      2    1
#10         2      2    2
```

If there are more columns, and want to sort based on the first 3 columns

```
df1 %>%
   arrange_at(1:3)
```

can also specify the column names wrapped with `vars`

---

Or use `arrange`

```
df1 %>%
   arrange(Household, person, trip)
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
df1[do.call(order, df1[c("Household", "person", "trip")]),]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Household = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), person = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
    trip = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: well , i have more columns but these 3 should be used for this part

Comment: Why ```do.call``` for base instead of ```df[order(df$Household, ...),]```?